# Reliably detect if computer is going to sleep

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

We're writing a Swift Application for mac where **we need to detect computer's sleep timestamps.**

---

We have figured out `NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification` and `NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification` are not reliable enough, because at rare occasions `NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification` would be called only after the PC wakes up and is able to process the current stack.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "idle times"? No user events, no processing, sleeping or something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited my question

Comment: Given your explanations (now removed), I think you might be talking about Power Nap? If this is the case I don't know any delegates for this (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15736). And you may want to file a radar about the NSWorkspace delegates not being reliable.

Comment: I would also assume that power nap leads to the behaviour where at rare occasions NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification would be called only after the PC wakes up and is able to process the current stack

Comment: In the end what alternative did you go with?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but pretty involved solution with backtracking afaik (go back in time to delete intervals where computer was probably sleeping). The API itself was not enough to cut it.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the disassembly of AppKit on 10.14.2, I have found that `NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification` is implemented on top of the lower-level IOKit `IORegisterForSystemPower` API. Therefore, using the higher-level AppKit API should be sufficient for most use cases.

One gotcha is that AppKit will enqueue the posting of the notification on the main run loop using `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` with `kCFRunLoopCommonModes`. Therefore, if your main thread is blocked or if the main run loop is currently running in a mode that is not one of the common modes, then the posting of the notification will be delayed. However, the power management system gives each process 30 seconds to respond to the notification, so it is highly unlikely that an app would be so blocked that it could miss the notification before the computer sleeps. (If it *is* likely to happen, then the app should be re-architected to not block the main thread anyways.)

Answer (score 2):

You can register callbacks with the system power manager (see `IORegisterForSystemPower`). Your callback functions are called when the system wants to go to sleep (you can suggest that it doesn't), is about to go to sleep, and when it wakes up again.

This Objective-C wrapper was contributed by Philip Dow over a decade ago and still works fine. I may have made slight modifications over the years so it compiles for the latest OS and Xcode, but it is otherwise unchanged. (Note: the original web site no longer exists, so I'll just paste it in here.) It would be trivial to rewrite this in Swift, bridge to the Obj-C code, or just use it as an example of using `IORegisterForSystemPower` and write your own callback functions (if you want exact times).

To use Philip's code, just call `+sharedPowerManagement` to create the singleton manager, then register observers with the notification center to receive `PDPowerManagementNotification` notifications. There's also a delegate use model.

```
//
//  PDPowerManagement.h
//  Originally part of the Journler project: http://journler.phildow.net
//  Source code available at http://developers.phildow.net
//
//  Created by Philip Dow on 3/21/06.
//  Licensed under the LGPL: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html
//  You may modify and redistribute the code as needed.
//  Please keep this original notice intact.
//
//  Of course, I would appreciate a mentioning in your app's about box.
//  If you make improvements or additions to the code, please let me know.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

//
// Be sure to include the IOKit Framework in your project

#import <mach/mach_port.h>
#import <mach/mach_interface.h>
#import <mach/mach_init.h>

#import <IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h>
#import <IOKit/IOMessage.h>

//
// Notifications
//
// The PDPowerManagementNotification will be sent to the default notification center
// with the shared instance of PDPowerManagement as the object. To make sure that a shared
// instance is available, call [PDPowerManagement sharedPowerManagement] somewhere in your code.
//
// The notification's user info dictionary will contain the PDPowerManagementMessage key with an
// NSNumber whose int value is either PDPowerManagementWillSleep or PDPowerManagementPoweredOn.

#define PDPowerManagementNotification   @"PDPowerManagementNotification"
#define PDPowerManagementMessage        @"PDPowerManagementMessage"
#define PDPowerManagementWillSleep      1
#define PDPowerManagementPoweredOn      3

//
// Disallowing Sleep
//
// There are two ways to disallow a power down. Either call setPermitSleep: with NO
// or implement the - (BOOL) shouldAllowIdleSleep:(id)sender delegate method and return NO as needed.
// At initialization _permitSleep is set to YES. With this value, the delegate method is
// always called if the delegate implements it. If _permitSleep is set to NO, the delegate
// method is never called. setPermitSleep: is thus a lazy way of always disallowing sleep.
//
// It must however be noted that it is not possible to cancel a sleep command that the user
// initiates. _permitSleep and the delegate method can only prevent an idle sleep. For
// more information: http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2004/qa1340.html

@interface PDPowerManagement : NSObject {

    BOOL    _permitSleep;
    id      _delegate;

}

+ (id)sharedPowerManagement;

- (BOOL) permitSleep;
- (void) setPermitSleep:(BOOL)permitSleep;

- (id) delegate;
- (void) setDelegate:(id)delegate;

- (void) _postPMNotification:(NSInteger)message;
- (BOOL) _shouldAllowSleep;

@end

//
// Delegation
// You should implement: - (BOOL) shouldAllowIdleSleep:(id)sender
//
// If you set a delegate, before the computer is put to idle sleep the delegate's
// shouldAllowSleep: method will be called. Return NO to disallow the power down,
// return yes to permit it.

@interface NSObject (PDPowerManagementDelegate)

//
// return YES to permit a power down, NO to disallow it
- (BOOL) shouldAllowIdleSleep:(id)sender;

@end
```

and

```
//
//  PDPowerManagement.m
//  Journler
//
//  Created by Philip Dow on 3/21/06.
//  Copyright 2006 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PDPowerManagement.h"

@implementation PDPowerManagement

PDPowerManagement   *_self;
io_connect_t        root_port;

static void callback(void * x,io_service_t y,natural_t messageType,void * messageArgument)
{
    switch ( messageType ) {
        case kIOMessageSystemWillSleep:
            if ( [_self _shouldAllowSleep] ) {
                [_self _postPMNotification:PDPowerManagementWillSleep];
                IOAllowPowerChange(root_port,(long)messageArgument);
            }
            else
                IOCancelPowerChange(root_port,(long)messageArgument);
            break;
        case kIOMessageCanSystemSleep:
            IOAllowPowerChange(root_port,(long)messageArgument);
            break;
        case kIOMessageSystemHasPoweredOn:
            [_self _postPMNotification:PDPowerManagementPoweredOn];
            break;
    }

}

#pragma mark -

+ (id)sharedPowerManagement {
    static PDPowerManagement *sharedPowerManagement = nil;

    if (!sharedPowerManagement)
        sharedPowerManagement = [[PDPowerManagement allocWithZone:NULL] init];

    return sharedPowerManagement;
}


- (id)init
{

    if ( (self=[super init])!=nil )
        {
        IONotificationPortRef   notify;
        io_object_t             anIterator;

        root_port = IORegisterForSystemPower (0,&notify,callback,&anIterator);
        if ( root_port == IO_OBJECT_NULL ) {
            NSLog(@"IORegisterForSystemPower failed");
            return nil;
        }

        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource(notify), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

        _permitSleep = YES;
        _self = self;

    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark -

- (BOOL) permitSleep { return _permitSleep; }

- (void) setPermitSleep:(BOOL)permitSleep {
    _permitSleep = permitSleep;
}

- (id) delegate { return _delegate; }

- (void) setDelegate:(id)delegate {
    _delegate = delegate;
}

#pragma mark -

- (void) _postPMNotification:(NSInteger)message {

    NSNumber *dictionaryMessage;
    NSDictionary *userInfo;
    NSNotification *notification;


    // Useful for debugging
    /*
    switch ( message ) {

        case PDPowerManagementWillSleep:
            NSLog(@"Going to sleep now");
            break;
        case PDPowerManagementPoweredOn:
            NSLog(@"Just had a nice snooze");
            break;

    }
    */

    dictionaryMessage = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:message];
    userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            dictionaryMessage, PDPowerManagementMessage, nil];
    notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:PDPowerManagementNotification
            object:self userInfo:userInfo];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];

}

- (BOOL) _shouldAllowSleep {

    if ( !_permitSleep )
        return NO;
    else {
        if ( _delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAllowIdleSleep:)] )
            return [_delegate shouldAllowIdleSleep:self];
        else
            return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: FWIW I recently attempted to port this to Swift.

The sticking point is that the kIOMessage constants (kIOMessageSystemWillSleep etc) are not available in Swift - they are not "constant" #defines, but are generated via nested macros.

(see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_macros_in_swift).

Of course it would be possible to hardcode the values in Swift, but that seems brittle if they ever changed. So, it's probably safer to stick with an Obj-C implementation until Apple fixes this.

Comment: On the other hand, these *are* constants in shipped versions of OS X/macOS, so they can't change without breaking existing code going back almost 2 decades now. In other words, the chance of Apple changing those values now is a probability so close to zero that it falls into the "won't ever happen" category.